# disable touch on the pseudo content of an element

Tags: html, css, angular, ionic2

Actually I have one toggle button component and I used the ::before pseudo class to insert text into it. Now when I'm clicking on toggle's button text , toggle button state changes. how to avoid this?

Ionic 2 code:

```
<ion-item>
    <ion-label>some content</ion-label>
    <ion-toggle (ionChange)="someMethod($event)"></ion-toggle>  
</ion-item>
```

classes :

```
 .toggle-icon {
    display: inline-block !important;
}

.item-inner {
    display: block;
}

ion-toggle::before {
    content: "Set as Default";
    padding-left: 11%;
}
```

Requirement: I can only create my required view by using above scheme.

**Expected:** I want someMethod() to be called when toggle button is clicked, not pseudo text.

Thanks for any help!!

Comment: method is not called now?

Comment: someMethod() is calling when we are clicking on "Set as Default" text, I want to remove this behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible to attach event listener to one element, but exclude that element's pseudo content. The reason is: pseudo content is not part of DOM, thus cannot be excluded from element selection.

However, you can listen the element (together with its pseudo content) and make exclusion inside the event listener function (`someMethod` in this case), by checking the clicked/touched position. Check this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cshao/oukc6bkd/) for example.

p.s. In your case, I guess the `:before` pseudo content is used to label toggle button? If yes, `<label>` tag is more appropriate.

Comment: thanks for your answer, I'm trying this because we can't place ion-toggle(toggle button and its label) with other contents in an ion-item so I'm trying alternative solution.

Comment: so my top view hierarchy is in ion-label(which is above the toggle button)and below I have toggle button with pseudo content.

Comment: @SandeepSharma is your question correctly answered? If yes, maybe you can kindly "accept" this answer?