# Ionic 2: find event.preventDefault , event.stopPropagation on ion-change

Tags: angular, ionic2

I have ion-toggle button binded with (ionChange). Somehow I'm not able to get event.preventDefault, event.stopPropagation methods on event object.

here is my code:

```
<ion-toggle (ionChange)="someMethod($event)"></ion-toggle> 

someMethod(e) {
  var offsetX = e.offsetX; // not finding offsetX
  if (offsetX > 20) {
    e.preventDefault(); // not finding preventDefault()
  }
}
```

Does anyone know how to get proper event object?

Comment: That should work. For `preventDefault` `(ionChange)="someMethod($event);false"` should also work

Comment: `preventDefault` only works on DOM events, not on values emitted by an `@Output()`. I don't know Inonic. Not sure what `ionChange` emits, but that shouldn't be too hard to find out.

Comment: @Sandeep have you got it done? In my case preventDefault is not working.

Answer (score 0):

[ion-toggle](http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/components/toggle/Toggle/) is a component specific to Ionic 2.

Also `ionChange` is an `@Output() event` emitted by the component. Check [here](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic/blob/master/src/components/toggle/toggle.ts#L119). 
[EventEmitters](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/EventEmitter-class.html) properties only emit the specific value which the component sends.
You will not receive the HTML DOM Event object through this for `preventDefaults` or `stopPropagation` as rightly said in the comments by @Gunter.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42711742/disable-touch-on-the-pseudo-content-of-an-element thread

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar situation with a toggle on Ionic v3 (legacy app).

With **ionChange** I couldn't stop the propagation, so I had to use **click** instead. The solution looks like this:

```
<ion-toggle (ionChange)="someBusinessLogic()" (click)="cancelPropagation($event)"></ion-toggle>

//Then, inside your class
cancelPropagation(event) {
  event.stopPropagation();
}
```